# Solve the recurrence relation $T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{2})+2$ when n is a power of 2

Tags: recurrence-relations

When n is 1, $T(n)=0$, when n is 2, $T(n)=2$, and when n is greater than 2,  $T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{2})+2$.

I am supposed to solve this exactly, not in big O notation. Since n is a power of 2, let $n=2^k$

$$T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{2})+2$$
$$T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{4})+4+2$$
$$T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{8})+4+4+2$$
$$...k times$$
$$T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{2^k})+4k+2=4k+2=4\log n+2$$
Does this make sense?

Comment: I would write it as $T(2^k)=2T(2^{k-1}) + 2$ rather than using $n$.

Comment: sure, but is my answer wrong?

Comment: Your answer is definitely not what they're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use $T(2^k)=2T(2^{k-1})+2$

$$T(2^0)=0$$
$$T(2^1)=2\cdot 0+2=2$$
$$T(2^2)=2\cdot2 +2=6$$
$$T(2^3)=2\cdot 6+2=14$$
$$T(2^4)=2\cdot14+2=30$$

You should be able to spot that $T(2^k)=2^{k+1}-2$. Can you prove it?